# How to check if number of rows = 6n-1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wish to count a number of rows in my sql database, and if the number of rows equal 6n-1 perform a function, if not, do nothing.

I know I can specify the integers to look for, but there would be thousands, so I wish to find a way where I can just define the math 6n-1

for example, when I count the rows in a table, I want to check whether there is 5,11,17 and so on.

If the number of rows match, do something, else do nothing.

Since 5,11,17.... is equal to every 6th row starting from 5, this can be expressed as 6n-1.

IS there a way to do this without defining every integer to check?

Comment: `if( $rowcount % 6 == 5)`...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ( $i=1 ; 6*$i-1 <= $database_rows ; $i++ ) {
  if ( 6*$i-1 == $database_rows ) {
    do_something();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
($rowcount + 1) % 6 == 0
```

perhaps...